# How to scale a rectangle with time in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

```
function timerHandle (e:TimerEvent)
{
    //loader.length = loader.length + 10

    txt_time.text = time;
    time--;
}
```

Loader is a rectangle movie clip. I need to lengthen it with time as a progress bar.
Please Help.

Comment: Did scaleX not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TweenLite for code animations, it's much more easier to deal with it, so in case of TweenLite code whould be:

```
//rectangle_mc is the rectangle movieclip or sprite
//1 is animation time in seconds
TweenLite.to(rectangle_mc, 1, {scaleX:2, scaleY:2});
```

You can find library here:
http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/